# How to set up django time_zone properly to used datetime properly in a view

Tags: mysql, django, timezone, django-timezone

In django 1.5,

i used in my settings... :

```
USE_TZ = True 
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
```

when i created an objects with

```
date_crea= auto_add_now()
```

at 16h20 on my computer in Paris,  on the mysql database, date_crea is set to 14h20 ...

On my admin list_display, i see 16h20 too but when i want to used date_crea in my view, my_objects.date_crea=14h20, why django know to show me the correct date on my admin list_display and not in my view ?

Comment: I have the same problem. `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe'` solve my problem, but this is not correct timezone from the list. So i'm still looking for solution.

Comment: Can you post little more about your view code? Like the actual view.py and then the template code.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 3.0.5

change the variable "USE_TZ = True" to "USE_TZ = False". That will work

Answer (score -2):

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' is the solution.

Comment: Not the solution, i need to used my time_zone data time on my process and not the UTC ...

Comment: Then change your server's time zone & time? And thanks for -1 ;)